# Laravel with nginx (ajenti) rewrite rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, nginx

I'm trying to move my existing local website to my server. I have ajenti installed that runs on nginx and does not support .htaccess files.

I've tried to covert the existing rules and add them in ajenti to: custom configuration but no luck. Also i've tried the rules on here: http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1442 but still no luck.

```
# nginx configuration
location / {
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
}
}
```

When I try to access the webpage (/profile for example) I get a 404 (not the 404 from laravel).

Greetz!

Answer (score 2):

1) First install PHP5 & CURL

```
apt-get install php5-fpm php5-cli php5-mcrypt curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
```

2) Enable PHP extensions (if not enabled):

```
php5enmod mcrypt
php5enmod curl
```

3) Install composer

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

4) Move composer to **/usr/local/bin** location

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

5) Create a new laravel project.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel /srv/domain.com/ 4.2.11
```

6) Keep proper permissions of laravel project or just use Ajenti magic button 
"**Fix file permissions**":

```
sudo chown -R :www-data /srv/domain.com/
chmod -R 775 /srv/domain.com/app/storage
```

Sometimes you may have to run an existing project. That time clone it to your directory.

7) In Ajenti admin panel "Websites" set the **website root path**:

```
/srv/domain.com/public
```

**Restart webservice using Ajenti button "Restart websites"** and check your domain.
You can see laravel project Interface.

8) Sometimes you will get an error:

```
403 error Nginx.
```

In this situation go to Ajenti admin panel "Websites":
Choose `domain.com` and go to "Advanced" tab. You can see "Custom configuration"
Paste to first field this code:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

**Then restart nginx or just press Ajenti button "Restart websites".**

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want to **hide .php files** exetensions, go to your website "Custom configuration" and paste to first field this code:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri.php?$query_string;
}
```